# What are Predictable Stochastic Processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have a question regarding the definition of a predictable process.

A random or stochastic process is *predictable* if we can determine the $n$th term if we have the knowledge of the past $n-1$ terms.

However my question is how can we possibly know the $n$th term if all the terms of this succession of values are random variables? I understand the mathematical definition of a predictable random process, but is it truly predictable in the sense you can determine exactly what the $n$th term is, or you can only know something like the expected value of the $n$th term but it still remains a random variable?

What is confusing to me is how a random variable could ever be "predictable" in any sense with absolute certainty, if it were it wouldn't be a random variable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct questions first:

> [...] is it truly predictable in the sense you can determine exactly what the $n$th term is, or you can only know something like the expected value of the $n$th term but it still remains a random variable?

It **is** still truly a random variable. For example, if $(X_n)$ is a sequence of random variables, then
$$ H_n = \max(X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1})$$
is still a random variable.

Now if we look at the filtration generated by the sequence $(X_n)$ then $(H_n)$ will be a predictable sequence with respect to it.

Do note that not every predictable sequence has to be a function of other variables. But when we deal with filtrations that are generated by a sequence of r.v.'s, then anything measurable with respect to it will necessarily be a function of those variables.
(Recall/try to prove the result that for two functions $f$ and $g$, $f\in \sigma (g) \implies f$ is a function of $g$. The converse is true too.)

> What is confusing to me is how a random variable could ever be "predictable" in any sense with absolute certainty, if it were it wouldn't be a random variable anymore.

Like in the example above, it's not *predictable* (in the English sense of the word) by itself, but rather it's predictable *given* all the other information at the time.

Hope this makes things clearer.